# Weird unwanted overflow inside CSS grid

Tags: html, css, grid, aspect-ratio

I am trying to make a grid which has two columns. The second column should contain an image input field which should be a square with a 1:1 aspect ratio. The square should be aligned with the bottom of the first column. Basically, the bottom of the image input should reach the bottom of the first column. I made a sketch of what I am trying to do in Figma (see the image).

**Note:** I cannot use the `aspect-ratio` property as it doesn't have great enough support yet for my needs. I also want to avoid magic numbers and JavaScript.

**What I've tried:** Currently, I am using the `width: 0;` + `padding: 0 100%;` trick to get a 1:1 aspect ratio. However, the image input is not pushing the other grid column back like I want and is instead overflowing. Additionally, the input doesn't seem to be getting a correct 1:1 aspect ratio either. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
section {
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: white;
}
input {
  background: #eee;
  border: 0.05rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  gap: 2rem;
}
.form-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}
.form-item ~ .form-item {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}


.image-input-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0 100%;
}
.image-input {
  background: #eee;
  border: 0.05rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid">
  
    <div>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-item">
      <label>Image</label>
      <div class="image-input-container">
        <button class="image-input">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I just set the `.image_input_container` to `{left: -20px}` with the other selectors

Comment: @Richie I dont see how that fixes anything?

Comment: Well, it did for me. I don't know why for you. Or did you want it to fix the height as well? You weren't specific on that

Comment: Is description to be a textarea rather than an input?

Comment: @AHaworth Either a textarea or an input is fine for my usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width: 0; padding: 0 100%;` 'trick' does not work because padding is calculated relative to the containing block **width**.

As you cannot use aspect-ratio, you could force the right hand column second item to be square for example by having an img element that is square and with the height of the left hand column. Then your div (into which I guess you will eventually place the image the user has chosen) can sit inside that cell taking its dimensions from it, but not affecting those dimensions as it is positioned absolute.

```html
<style>
  body {
    background: #eee;
  }
  
  section {
    margin: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    background: white;
  }
  
  input {
    background: #eee;
    border: 0.05rem solid black;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
  
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
    gap: 2rem;
  }
  
  .form-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.25rem;
  }
  
  .form-item~.form-item {
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  
  .image-input-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  
  .image-input {
    background: #eee;
    border: 0.05rem solid black;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .dummy {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
</style>
<section>
  <div class="grid">

    <div>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <label>Image</label>
      <div class="image-input-container">
        <img class="dummy" width="1" height="1">
        <button class="image-input">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
section {
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #eee;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7fr minmax(auto, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;
}

.form-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.form-item~.form-item {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.image_input_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.image_input {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid">
    <div>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
      <label>Image</label>
      <div class="image_input_container">
        <button class="image_input">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Maybe you can use minmax for defining columns and padding-top:100% for keeping aspect ratio. Check it out the sample code, i hope that help.

Comment: This makes the overflow go away but now the image input is not expending to the bottom and not aligning with the bottom of the description input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, wrapped the 2 input forms and removed padding:100% and width:0

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
  }
  section {
    margin: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    background: white;
  }
  input {
    background: #eee;
    border: 0.05rem solid black;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
  
  
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80% 1fr;
    gap: 2rem;
  }

  .input-divs{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .form-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 0.25rem;
  }
  .form-item ~ .form-item {
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  
  
  .image-input-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .image-input {
    background: #eee;
    border: 0.05rem solid black;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="input-divs">
            <div class="form-item">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <label>Image</label>
            <div class="image-input-container">
            <button class="image-input">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The image block isn't square.

Comment: @A Haworth ok I see.